# Consuming an api that has a websocket endpoint in C#

Tags: c#, xml, api, websocket

I have this API that i need to consume in windows form app but the endpoint is using a websocket and accept a simple xml request and also returns the response in xml,but don't really know how to go about it in C#, is there a library i have to download to be able to consume it.

sample request

```
<request>
<command>getSerialPortList</command>
</request>
```

Endpoint:

```
ws://localhost:1335
```

Comment: A good start would probably be looking at the `websocket` documentation and associated tutorials and examples

Comment: @MichaelRandall can you recommend one for me and also maybe a link to the tutorials,thanks in anticipation